# Using a $row variable inside of $_POST variable for a MYSQL query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that allows uploads of images. The user can select which gallery to upload the image to based on a radio button.

In the upload php script, the images are uploaded to a directory then then directory location is added to a MYSQL database. The upload and directory addition works fine.

I'm trying to add the name of the radio button that was pressed to another column in the image database so that I can see which image was uploaded to which gallery as my images are in a separate table.

My form looks like

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="upload-image.php" method="POST">
<h3>Select Gallery To Upload To</h3>
<?php
    $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($results)) 
    {
        echo'<br>';
        echo '<input type="radio" name="'. $row["username"].'"value="'.$row["username"].'">' . $row["username"];
    }
?>
<input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000" />
Choose a file to upload: <input name="uploadedfile" type="file" /><br />
<input type="submit" value="Upload File" />
</form>
```

The section of the upload script that handles the adding to the MYSQL database is as follows:

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (image, gallery_name) VALUES('".$target_path, $_POST["$row["name"]"]."')")
```

This is giving me a few errors:
Notice: Undefined index: name

Warning: mysql_query() expects parameter 2 to be resource, string given

How might I fix this?

Comment: Don't use `mysql_*` functions! They're in the process of being [deprecated](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/faq.databases.php#faq.databases.mysql.deprecated).

Comment: Print $_POST array and the query also.  The value $_POST["$row["name"]"] will not be available in the query .

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/q0gwD). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/OWwr2)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/orrj0) and use either [PDO](http://goo.gl/TD3xh) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/YXyWL) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/b2ATO). Also see [Why shouldn't I use mysql functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/J5jAo)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/14331907/922198

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query's double quotes are a bit awry. You also need to feed `mysql_query` a resource created by `mysql_connect` (in the following example, it's represented by `$mysql`).

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (image, gallery_name) VALUES('".$target_path."', '". $_POST[$row["name"]]."')", $mysql);
```

Comment: I've only used this to view items from a database before, EG $results = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users");

So I'm not 100% sure on whats actually happening here.

Comment: @MichaelN what in particular is confusing to you?

Comment: If I have say $mysql ("INSERT INTO image etc") then doesn't something have to be done with $mysql afterwards? The only time I've used something like this is to get a row of results, and then echo it out, so after doing $mysql("SELECT* FROM users etc") id then echo $mysql so something was being done with the variable.

I hope this makes sense.

Comment: For `INSERT`s `mysql_query` returns a boolean value based on the success of the query.

Answer (score 1):

the string is not concatnated (joined) properly.

change

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (image, gallery_name) VALUES('".$target_path, $_POST["$row["name"]"]."')")
```

to

```
$row_data = $row["name"];
mysql_query("INSERT INTO images (image, gallery_name) VALUES('".$target_path."', '".$_POST[$row_data]."')");
```

Comment: You're almost there, but not quite.

Comment: Hmm this seems to give me more errors.

Notice: Undefined variable: row
Notice: Undefined index: